# window.print(); Not working in this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to print web page after done some events on server side but window.print in not working. how i solve this problem.
My page source code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="butPrint" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/print.gif"
                    ToolTip="Click to Print" 
                    onclick="butPrint_Click" />


 protected void butPrint_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ///my events
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "print", "printPage();", true);
    }


function printPage() {
     // here i have hide some controls

     window.print();

    }
```

This is working on firefox but not working in IE 8

Comment: Please define "`not working`".

Comment: put a try and catch around window.print() or in the printPage and c if any exception

Comment: @Teemu page not printing